# Would running Ubuntu (or another distro) on my low spec computer instead of windows improve performance much?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, performance

Trying to get the most out of a low-end HP laptop running windows 10 It runs alright provided I don't open more than 2 intensive programs at once. I've used Ubuntu on it before (dual boot) but did not fully switch over was mostly just trying out different OS. Is there an advantage performance wise? 
My [specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd9yi.png)
Also, the hard drive is almost 30G but mostly taken up by windows, I use a USB for storage of programs and pictures

And sorry if anything here seems stupid, I'm new to the site

Comment: Arguably it will perform slightly better with Ubuntu, especially with less demanding variants like Xubuntu or Lubuntu, but really nothing to talk about. It's an very entry level Celeron with only 2GB of RAM. Do not expect miracles, they don't exist, at all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes and no.

The operating system itself will run smoother, easier, yes, and as a plus it will not take as much hard drive space (irrelevant). But the computer can only do what it is capable of, changing the operating system will not improve performance of applications unless they are slightly more optimized for that operating system. They still take the same amount of resources for the same tasks.

On the other hand, it will improve performance because windows runs a lot more background processes, and does many other things to slow itself down, and when the OS is not taking up as many resources as it would on windows, it will allocate more for your intensive usage. So, ***in theory, yes, Ubuntu will be faster and be able to run your applications more smoothly.***

As a tip, if you want more speed out of it, it would be very smart to go with the XFCE version of ubuntu, it is a lighter version on the GUI side of things, so it's better for your case.

And no worries, we were all new at one point ! :) Cheers. Hope this helps clear it up a little bit.